# Fixing missing key=value pairs using array_walk and closure

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a data coming in from an external source and it drops parts of the data structure when null instead of passing them as nulls. I'm trying to execute a little pre-processing to avoid errors later on using array_walk with a closure. This is what I have and I think it should work, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Note: the keys in the arrays being walked are in the values

**Code:**

```
  1 <?php
  2     $lead = array (
  3         'contactId' => '63bda0xxxxx55feab6d671',
  4         'contactPhone' => '9175550154',
  6         'lastName' => 'Cxxx',
  7         'email' => 'xxx@yahoo.com',
  8         'lists' => array (
  9             0 => array (
 10                 'id' => '62a3810xxxxxa8be2',
 11                 'name' => 'Unlimited5gHomeInternet',
 12             ),
 13         ),
 14         'customFields' => array (
 15         ),
 16         'subscriptionStatus' => 'OPT_IN',
 17         'created' => '2023-01-10T17:28:06.599Z',
 18         'updated' => '2023-01-10T17:28:06.599Z', 'updateSource' => 'WEB_FORM',
 19     );
 20     $expected_keys_1 = ['contactPhone', 'firstname', 'lastName', 'contactPhone','email'];
 21     $expected_keys_2 = ['zip_coode', 'address', 'city', 'state'];
 22
 23     array_walk($expected_keys_1, function($value,$key) use (&$lead){
 24         if(!isset($lead['$value'])){ $lead += array('$key' => null); }
 25     });
 26
 27     array_walk($expected_keys_2, function($value,$key) use (&$lead){
 28         if(!isset($lead['customFields']['$value'])){$lead += array('$key' => null);}
 29     });
 30     var_export($lead);
```

**Results:**

```
 array (
  'contactId' => '63bda026f895a55feab6d671',
  'contactPhone' => '9178050154',
  'firstName' => 'Juan',
  'lastName' => 'Cueto',
  'email' => 'wanchy@yahoo.com',
  'lists' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'id' => '62a381052b9f1f18ae8a8be2',
      'name' => 'Unlimited5gHomeInternet',
    ),
  ),
  'customFields' =>
  array (
  ),
  'subscriptionStatus' => 'OPT_IN',
  'created' => '2023-01-10T17:28:06.599Z',
  'updated' => '2023-01-10T17:28:06.599Z',
  'updateSource' => 'WEB_FORM',
  '$key' => NULL,
)
```

**Desired Results:**

```
 array (
  'contactId' => '63bda026f895a55feab6d671',
  'contactPhone' => '9178050154',
  'firstname => NULL,
  'lastName' => 'Cueto',
  'email' => 'wanchy@yahoo.com',
  'lists' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'id' => '62a381052b9f1f18ae8a8be2',
      'name' => 'Unlimited5gHomeInternet',
    ),
  ),
  'customFields' =>
  array (
      'zip_code' => NULL,
      'address' => NULL,
      'state' => NULL,
      'state' => NULL,
  ),
  'subscriptionStatus' => 'OPT_IN',
  'created' => '2023-01-10T17:28:06.599Z',
  'updated' => '2023-01-10T17:28:06.599Z',
  'updateSource' => 'WEB_FORM',
  '$key' => NULL,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close, this is the code that worked:

```
array_walk($expected_keys_1, function($value,$key) use (&$lead){
        if(!isset($lead[$value])){ $lead += array($value => null); }
});

array_walk($expected_keys_2, function($value,$key) use (&$lead){
        if(!isset($lead['customFields'][$value])){$lead['customFields'] += array($value => null);}
});
```

Comment: Writing the question and trying to give anticipate requested questions ahead of time was key in me organizing my own thoughts to figuring this out on my own and this is the 5th time that's happened (though two were answered in the suggested article which is a new experience for me). Someone on the php forum suggested I posted the answered question anyways in case it would help someone else. :)